# How to add CRLF/line break in Inno Setup custom message

Tags: inno-setup

Can I add CRLF (carriage return + line feed) in `[CustomMessages]` section?

Regards.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The documentation on the [`[Messages]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=messagessection) says:

> "%n" creates a line break.

---

See for example how the standard `SetupAppRunningError` is defined in the `Default.isl`:

```
SetupAppRunningError=Setup has detected that %1 is currently running.%n%nPlease close all instances of it now, then click OK to continue, or Cancel to exit.
```